# "The attached PDF file is not a PDF file. Please remove file, create PDF and reattach."

Tags: provisional-application, pdf, sb0016

I am getting the error "The attached PDF file is not a PDF file. Please remove file, create PDF and reattach." for the SB0016 - provisional patent PDF form.

I downloaded the file from their own server here: https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/sb0016.pdf and then saved it to my mac - filled it out using the default mac osx program preview and get this error when uploading their file.

I am uploading to their 'unregistered' website here: https://efs.uspto.gov/EFSWebUIUnregistered/EFSWebUnregistered?ActionString=go

I get this error when uploading a completely blank and unedited version of their own PDF, and I get this error when I try to edit their PDF before uploading it.

does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: have you used the Finder info to see what kind of a file your Mac thinks it is? Preview should work but you could also try Adobe Reader. FYI - EFS-Web is very fussy about imbedded fonts and page size.

Comment: You might try File>Print...>PDF>Save as PDF. This sometimes produces cleaner PDFs than just saving the file with changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing 'file > export as pdf' worked for me (but not 'save as pdf' for some reason)

Comment: But we are supposed to print it, sign it, scan it, and only then do we give it to USPTO.  So, how do you do that using "export as pdf"?

Comment: "export" did not work for me.  I used "curl" at the unix command line; that helped.  As for a signed copy, I have scanned on an old Windows 7 machine, and on a Mac, using Adobe Acrobat of different eras, but nothing worked.